# second argument Object.create

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-5

My expectation was that I'd overwrite Vehicle's toString method with a new toString method. However this doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. Based on this article it looks like it should https://strongloop.com/strongblog/an-introduction-to-javascript-es6-classes/ (scroll down to Class Extending)

```
function Vehicle(make, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.year = year;
}

Vehicle.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.make + ' ' + this.year;
};

var vehicle = new Vehicle('Toyota Corolla', 2009);

function Motorcycle(make, year) {
  Vehicle.apply(this, [make, year]);
}

Motorcycle.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype, {
  toString: function() {
    return 'Motorcycle ' + this.make + ' ' + this.year;
  }
});

Motorcycle.prototype.constructor = Motorcycle;

var motorcycle = new Motorcycle('harley', 2010);
console.log(motorcycle.toString()); //TypeError
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The properties object given as the second argument of `Object.create` is supposed to contain property descriptors, not just values. This corrects the issue:

```
Motorcycle.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype, {
  toString: {
    configurable: true, enumerable: true, writable: true, 
    value: function() {
      return 'Motorcycle ' + this.make + ' ' + this.year;
    }
  }
});
```

See also the [MDN reference for `Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realized the value property was necessary. Just want to add that the other property values don't need to be changed. They're just initialized to false by default.

Comment: Indeed; true for all of them is simply consistent with the way properties are ordinarily created, like `Vehicle.prototype.toString` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

to override the method, first point the Motorcycle's prototype constructor to itself.
 please read the **comments**  in the below code .

```
Vehicle.prototype.toString = function() {
return this.make + ' ' + this.year;
};

var vehicle = new Vehicle('Toyota Corolla', 2009);

function Motorcycle(make, year) {
Vehicle.apply(this, [make, year]);
}

Motorcycle.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype); //Motorcycle.prototype is an object that inherits from Vehicle.prototype
// and is still pointing to the Vehicle constructor 

Motorcycle.prototype.constructor = Motorcycle; // changing the constructor back to Motorcycle;

// method overridden after Motorcycle is pointing its own constructor
// now override the toString method
Motorcycle.prototype.toString=function(){
console.log("inside the motorcycle toString ")
}

var motorcycle = new Motorcycle('harley', 2010);
console.log(motorcycle.toString());
```